# Options set for Firebase Functions gen2 in code are not being applied

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to use the **best practice**, set options (`minInstances, timeout, ...`) on a configuration object inside the function code. I use Function Gen2 to expose an Express app to HTTP endpoints.

```
import { onRequest as onRequestV2 } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
export const myAPI = onRequestV2(
  {
    timeoutSeconds: 66,
    minInstances: 1,
  },
  myAPIExpressAppHandler,   // This is Express app, app = express();
);
```

due to this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#set_runtime_options

Code run fine, deployment run fine, but the options does not apply (view on https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/), it is still the default option (E.g.: `minInstances = 0`)

We are using `firebase-functions@3.24.1` (latest of v3). I cannot update to v4 at the moment.

Setting the options for Function Gen1 work totally fine.

**Do you have any clue for it?**